# is there any way to popView controller in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have an application in **storyboard** and make the connections to `second view controller` by push operation in the storyboard itself(without using coding).

Is there any way to pop to `first view controller` without writing any code and using the storyboard?

Note:by using `navigation controller`  we will have `back` button but if a button is created in the second view controller and when we tap on that button we should pop  to first view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboards doesn't provide a "no-code" way to popViewController, you need to implement by yourself.

And if you want to pop to the first viewController you need to use:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Storyboards don't provide a way to return from a segue without coding, but this can be easily accomplished with this code:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `UnwindSegue` as well since iOS6, although it does require some code)* for push segues. For a good explanation of `UnwindSegues`, see [SO post, scroll down to "In a Nutshell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them)

)*Specifically, you need an unwind action, e.g.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToThisViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that involves writing code once but can be used afterwards in your storyboards as a segue without further implementations would be some kind of PopSegue as subclass of a UIStoryboardSegue.

```
@interface PopSegue : UIStoryboardSegue
```

Overwrite the -perform method as follows.

```
@implementation PopSegue

- (void)perform
{
    [[self.sourceViewController navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Use a custom segue for back-navigation and specify the PopSegue class.